# Polygon Rotation using matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: matlab

Consider the polygon with vertices `(0, 0), (1, 0), (7/10, 1), (1/2, 1/2), and (3/10, 1)`. Make a plot of this polygon in Matlab using the fill function. Rotate this polygon by an angle of `100` degrees using matrix-vector multiplication in Matlab with an appropriately chosen rotation matrix R. Make another plot of the rotated polygon using fill.

```
% Makes original polygon 
X = [0 1 7/10 1/2 3/10];
Y = [0 0 1 1/2 1];
norm_poly = fill(X,Y,'k');

thetad  = 100;
R = [cosd(thetad) -sind(thetad); sind(thetad) cosd(thetad)];
C = repmat([0 0], 5, 1)';
axis([-10 10 -10 10])
V = get(norm_poly,'Vertices')';  % get the current set of vertices
V = R*(V - C) + C;             % do the rotation relative to the centre of the 
square
set(norm_poly,'Vertices',V');    % update the vertices
```

How would I make to different plots to show them? Does the code to rotate make sense and answer all the requirements?

Comment: Are you just looking for a method of displaying two different plots? Or for advice on the rotation? In the former case the title is misleading.

Comment: Both, sorry for the confusion. I want to make sure that my code makes sense. Also I need to figure out how to display the two different plots

Comment: `C = repmat([0 0], 5, 1)';` is not the center of the polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rotation itself makes sense. To plot multiple things to the same graph use `hold on` after making the first plot. Alternatively you can make a new `figure` and plot a new `fill` there.

```
P = [0, 1, 7/10, 1/2, 3/10;
     0, 0, 1,    1/2, 1];
fill(P(1,:), P(2,:), 'k');

theta = 100;
R = @(t) [cosd(t) -sind(t); sind(t) cosd(t)];

axis([-3 3 -3 3])
grid on
V = R(theta)*P;

hold on;
fill(V(1,:), V(2,:), 'k');
```